# Curl and Google Image

Tags: curl

I tried to scrape Google image search result page with curl from Terminal, but it doesn't give me an actual html source that I can view with "View Page Source" in Firefox. I tried both "curl [url]" and "curl -L [url]". Both gave me a short html source that includes "Your client does not have permission to get URL " "from this server". How can I get the html source that I can get in Firefox with a shell script?

Part of the short html I got in Terminal said this.

> Please see Google's Terms of Service posted at
>   http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html
>
> If you believe
>   that you have received this response in error, please report
>   your problem. However, please make sure to take a look at our Terms of
>   Service (http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html). In your email,
>   please send us the **entire** code displayed below.

Comment: @JigglyNaga yes. I edited my question.

Comment: Just checking, were you *polite* and waited a couple of seconds between each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message contains a broken link, but [Google's current terms of service](https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/policies/terms/) say:

> Do not misuse our Services, for example, do not interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method **other than the interface and the instructions that we provide**.

(emphasis mine)

They're refusing your request for some reason.  It could be that they've seen suspicious activity from your IP address, but it's most probably that they've spotted that you're using `curl` instead of a regular browser (in which you would see the adverts).

You could make `curl` imitate such a browser, by providing a common user-agent (eg. from http://www.browser-info.net/useragents) to the `-A` option, but that would still be violating the ToS.

Answer (score 2):

I would think it's most likely an issue with cookies (or lack thereof). You may want to try playing around with curl's `-c [file]` option for its cookie jar, saving cookies to a file.
You may have to script a curl request to say "google.com" to submit the image search and save any cookies to `file`, and then a second query to scrape the web url you're given for the actual search and load the saved cookies using the `-b [file]` option. It may be that it just needs the session ID cookie.

You can see in the screenshot below that Google assigns a number of cookie variables.

[image: Cookies example for google images]